# Retrieving image id by image name - WORDPRESS REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is there any way I could retrieve image id by image name (example.png) using rest api? I have been trying to find a solution, but without any luck.

Comment: Do you mean you the html ID or the attachment ID from Wordpress?

Comment: Id from media library on wordpress site

Answer (score 1):

```
let mediaUrl = "https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media";

function getImageId(imageName) {

  // Step 1: Search for the Image by Name
  let searchParams = "?search=" + encodeURIComponent(imageName);
  let searchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mediaUrl + searchParams);
  let searchResults = JSON.parse(searchResponse.getContentText());

  // Step 2: Retrieve the Image ID
  if (searchResults.length > 0) {
    let imageId = null;
    // Get the ID of the first image found (assumes unique names)
    imageId = searchResults[0].id; 
  }
  return imageId;
}
```